# dynamic image resizing after asynchronously downloading it from the firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am trying to dynamically adjust the image size depending upon the image that I download from the firebase database and present it in the table view cell. I want the width of the image to be the frame width and the height to adjust accordingly.

**I have a customImageView class to download image asynchronously from firebase**

I've tried many methods but in vain. Is there a super clean way to adjust the image size dynamically :-D

this Is my cell :

```
class viewControllerHomeCell: UITableViewCell  { 

   @IBOutlet var mainImage: CstmImageView!

  }
```

my cell for row at :

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellData =  TableViewControllerHome.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! viewControllerHomeCell

    cellData.mainImage.loadImagesWithUrl(from: self.postArray[indexPath.row].covrImgUrl)
  }
```

and this is a UIImageView subclass to load images from the firebase async. :

```
class CstmImageView : UIImageView {
let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()

var imageUrlString : String?
func loadImagesWithUrl(from imageUrl : String!)  {
    imageUrlString = imageUrl
    self.image = nil

    if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: imageUrl as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
        self.image = cachedImage
        return
    }

    let url = URLRequest(url: URL(string: imageUrl)!)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, eror) in

        if eror != nil {
            print(eror!)
            return
        }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data : data!) {
                if self.imageUrlString == imageUrl {
                  self.image = downloadedImage
                }
                self.imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: imageUrl as AnyObject)
            }

        }
    }.resume()
 }
}
```

any help is appreciated a a lot : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your imageView Height Outlet and connect with your imageView height constrain

```
class viewControllerHomeCell: UITableViewCell  { 

    @IBOutlet var mainImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var viewImageViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
 }
```

And Use Pod for Download Image

pod 'SDWebImage'

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
 {
     let cellData =  TableViewControllerHome.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! viewControllerHomeCell

        cellData.mainImage.sd_setImage(with:URL.init(string: "Pass Yor image Url string here"))
        { (image, error, imageCacheType, url) in

             cellData.mainImage.image = image

             viewImageViewHeight.constant =  image?.size.height
        }

        cellData.mainImage.loadImagesWithUrl(from: self.postArray[indexPath.row].covrImgUrl)
}
```

Comment: Yes you can take reference of Height constrain in your CstmImageView class and ones you get image you can update height constraint constant. But i prefer to use SDWebImage its easy to use.

Comment: thank you, buddy, but, what's that UserProfile!.profile_image!  and is there a way I could achieve it without the pod

Comment: Its image URL that you have to pass your 

            self.postArray[indexPath.row].covrImgUrl